# Как более оптимально добавлять иконки в HTML при верстке сайтов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, icon

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, если такая иконка в SVG (пример)

```html
<svg width="29" height="36" viewBox="0 0 29 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M14.4995 1.7998C9.50223 1.7998 5.4375 5.675 5.4375 10.4393C5.4375 16.8366 13.596 22.96 13.9431 23.2175C14.1062 23.3393 14.3029 23.3998 14.4995 23.3998C14.6962 23.3998 14.8929 23.3393 15.056 23.2175C15.4031 22.96 23.5625 16.8366 23.5625 10.4393C23.5625 5.675 19.4969 1.7998 14.4995 1.7998ZM14.4995 21.4143C12.7141 19.9566 7.25009 15.1154 7.25009 10.4393C7.25009 6.62803 10.5019 3.52787 14.4995 3.52787C18.4972 3.52787 21.7499 6.62803 21.7499 10.4393C21.7499 15.1068 16.2849 19.9549 14.4995 21.4143Z" fill="#383838"/>
  <path d="M14.5 6.2998C12.0015 6.2998 9.96875 8.3185 9.96875 10.7998C9.96875 13.2811 12.0015 15.2998 14.5 15.2998C16.9985 15.2998 19.0312 13.2811 19.0312 10.7998C19.0312 8.3185 16.9985 6.2998 14.5 6.2998ZM14.5 13.4998C13.0011 13.4998 11.7812 12.2884 11.7812 10.7998C11.7812 9.3112 13.0011 8.0998 14.5 8.0998C15.9989 8.0998 17.2188 9.3112 17.2188 10.7998C17.2188 12.2884 15.9989 13.4998 14.5 13.4998Z" fill="#383838"/>
</svg>
```

Как лучше при верстке ее использовать?

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Напрямую SVG тэг в HTML
2. Переделать в PNG и напрямую в HTML
3. В CSS через background background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, 'SVG тэг'")  no-repeat;
4. В CSS через background background в PNG: url("PNG")  no-repeat;

Хочется найти самый оптимальный вариант с точки зрения SEO и скорости, особенно если иконок таких будет несколько десятков на странице.

Comment: думаю лучше юзать готовые паки иконок по типу `font-awesome`  либо `material-ui` и их через тег i вставлять, ваш вариант в большей степени для наиболее сложной работы с svg

Comment: @Andrey Freiz, иконки все пользовательские и разные

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Хочется найти самый оптимальный вариант с точки зрения SEO и скорости,
> особенно если иконок таких будет несколько десятков на странице.

Для SEO с точки зрения индексации, самый лучший вариант добавление инлайн SVG код в HTML.

У SVG есть два тега `<desc>` и `<title>`, в которые вы можете написать любой нужный вам текст для индексации поисковиками.

`<title > Фирма Орион </title>`
И этот текст кроме того, что будет проиндексирован, дополнительно выводится в качестве подсказки при наведении курсора.

`<desc> Наша фирма Орион оказывает следующие услуги ......</desc>`
Этот текст пользователь не увидит, но он также будет проиндексирован.

Ещё преимущество инлайн добавления - беcпроблемная стилизация иконок.

```css
#marker {
stroke:#383838;
fill:#383838;
}
#marker:hover {
stroke:red;
fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="29" height="36" viewBox="0 0 29 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<desc> Наша фирма Орион оказывает следующие услуги ......</desc>
 <g id="marker" pointer-events="all" > 
 <title > Фирма Орион </title>
 <path  d="M14.4995 1.7998C9.50223 1.7998 5.4375 5.675 5.4375 10.4393C5.4375 16.8366 13.596 22.96 13.9431 23.2175C14.1062 23.3393 14.3029 23.3998 14.4995 23.3998C14.6962 23.3998 14.8929 23.3393 15.056 23.2175C15.4031 22.96 23.5625 16.8366 23.5625 10.4393C23.5625 5.675 19.4969 1.7998 14.4995 1.7998ZM14.4995 21.4143C12.7141 19.9566 7.25009 15.1154 7.25009 10.4393C7.25009 6.62803 10.5019 3.52787 14.4995 3.52787C18.4972 3.52787 21.7499 6.62803 21.7499 10.4393C21.7499 15.1068 16.2849 19.9549 14.4995 21.4143Z" />
  <path  d="M14.5 6.2998C12.0015 6.2998 9.96875 8.3185 9.96875 10.7998C9.96875 13.2811 12.0015 15.2998 14.5 15.2998C16.9985 15.2998 19.0312 13.2811 19.0312 10.7998C19.0312 8.3185 16.9985 6.2998 14.5 6.2998ZM14.5 13.4998C13.0011 13.4998 11.7812 12.2884 11.7812 10.7998C11.7812 9.3112 13.0011 8.0998 14.5 8.0998C15.9989 8.0998 17.2188 9.3112 17.2188 10.7998C17.2188 12.2884 15.9989 13.4998 14.5 13.4998Z" />
 </g> 
</svg>
```

Основной недостаток инлайн добавления - при большом количестве svg иконок, код HTML сильно увеличивается.

Эту задачу решают спрайты SVG с набором нужных иконок. Спрайт загружается один раз при помощи тега `<object>`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/symbol/sprite.svg">
  Your  browser does not support SVG 
</object>
```

и затем, каждая иконка вызывается из спрайта на любой странице HTML сколько угодно раз при помощи тега `<use>`

```
<svg>
      <use  xlink:href="sprite.svg"#icons--icon1"></use>
</svg>
```

Другие способы вставки SVG иконок `<img>`, `background`, `content` имеют те или иные недостатки в проблемности стилизации, анимации, масштабируемости

И отсюда резонный вопрос, - зачем использовать масштабируемую графику SVG в качестве фона, когда при этом теряются основные преимущества SVG.
Нужен просто фон? Тогда однозначно нужен png.

Answer (score 3):

Всё зависит от конкретной задачи, ведь `PNG` не масштабируется в отличие от `SVG`.

Если масштабируемость не важна, то нужно выбирает вариант с меньшим размером, сложные `SVG` иконки, думаю, будут весить больше обычных `PNG`.

Я бы предложил 5-й вариант: все пользовательские иконки объединить в один `PNG`-спрайт. Таким образом вы уменьшаете общий размер чуть ли не в разы и уменьшаете количество запросов на сервер.

И ещё, в зависимости от итогового размера спрайта, если он не сильно большой, можно конвертировать его в `base64`, вовсе избегая таким образом запросов на сервер. Но нужно учитывать тот факт, что конвертация в `base64` увеличивает размер примерно на треть.

Answer (score 2):

### Добавление иконок с помощью спрайта PNG

Допустим есть спрайт PNG социальных иконок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем его в HTML

`background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJIfS.png");`

И с помощью изменения параметров `background-position`, как-бы меняем цвет иконок при наведении курсора.  На самом деле вместо черно белой иконки будет показан его цветной вариант.

*1. Светлая тема*

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJIfS.png");
  transition: 0.5s;
 }

.v2 {
  background-position: -85px 0px;
}

.v3 {
  background-position: -170px 0px;
}
.v4 {
  background-position: -255px 0px;
}
.v5 {
  background-position: -340px 0px;
}

.v1:hover {
  background-position: 0 -86px;
}

.v2:hover  {
  background-position: -85px -84px;
}

.v3:hover  {
  background-position: -170px -84px;
} 
.v4:hover  {
  background-position: -255px -84px;
}
.v5:hover  {
  background-position: -340px -84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block v1"></div>
  <div class="block v2"></div>
  <div class="block v3"></div>
  <div class="block v4"></div>
  <div class="block v5"></div>
</div>
```

2. Тёмная тема

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJIfS.png");
  transition: 0.5s;
  
}

.v1 {
  background-position: 0 -170px;
}

.v2 {
  background-position: -85px -170px;
}

.v3 {
  background-position: -170px -170px;
}
.v4 {
  background-position: -255px -170px;
}
.v5 {
  background-position: -340px -170px;
}

.v1:hover {
  background-position: 0 -86px;
}

.v2:hover  {
  background-position: -85px -84px;
}

.v3:hover  {
  background-position: -170px -84px;
} 
.v4:hover  {
  background-position: -255px -84px;
}
.v5:hover  {
  background-position: -340px -84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block v1"></div>
  <div class="block v2"></div>
  <div class="block v3"></div>
  <div class="block v4"></div>
  <div class="block v5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```html
<svg width="29" height="36" viewBox="0 0 29 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M14.4995 1.7998C9.50223 1.7998 5.4375 5.675 5.4375 10.4393C5.4375 16.8366 13.596 22.96 13.9431 23.2175C14.1062 23.3393 14.3029 23.3998 14.4995 23.3998C14.6962 23.3998 14.8929 23.3393 15.056 23.2175C15.4031 22.96 23.5625 16.8366 23.5625 10.4393C23.5625 5.675 19.4969 1.7998 14.4995 1.7998ZM14.4995 21.4143C12.7141 19.9566 7.25009 15.1154 7.25009 10.4393C7.25009 6.62803 10.5019 3.52787 14.4995 3.52787C18.4972 3.52787 21.7499 6.62803 21.7499 10.4393C21.7499 15.1068 16.2849 19.9549 14.4995 21.4143Z" fill="#383838"/>
  <path d="M14.5 6.2998C12.0015 6.2998 9.96875 8.3185 9.96875 10.7998C9.96875 13.2811 12.0015 15.2998 14.5 15.2998C16.9985 15.2998 19.0312 13.2811 19.0312 10.7998C19.0312 8.3185 16.9985 6.2998 14.5 6.2998ZM14.5 13.4998C13.0011 13.4998 11.7812 12.2884 11.7812 10.7998C11.7812 9.3112 13.0011 8.0998 14.5 8.0998C15.9989 8.0998 17.2188 9.3112 17.2188 10.7998C17.2188 12.2884 15.9989 13.4998 14.5 13.4998Z" fill="#383838"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]